# How do i make a component like this in react?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

What I needed was something like that shown in the picture. I need to show certain names and if the names list exceeds more than 2 rows I need to show  `+n others`. If the user clicks `+n others` the list needs to be expanded to show all the others.

Is there any component available in react to get this result? I have seen it on a number of websites but don't know what they are called.

I could write the component myself but the difficult part would be how many names to show before i show the +n others. I can only show 2 rows initially and each name can be of variable length. So in one case, a single name may take up the entire 1st row and in others, i may be able to fit 3 names.

Comment: What have you tried ? [To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @sebastienbarbier I got completely lost as I do not know if such a component is available. I looked through some popular react UI libraries but could not find anything related to this.

Comment: It's a very easy component to implement, start by buidling a simple case wit a list of clickable label without pagination, then define a boolean show/hide, if show is True you display a button, if show if False you show the rest of your list.

Comment: The difficult part would be how many names to show before i show the `+n others`. I can only show 2 rows initially and each name can be of variable length. So in one case   a single name may take up the entire 1st row and in others i may be able to fit 3 names.

Comment: That's a perfect question for stackoverflow as soon as you have a working prototype with code to show . Start with simple case, then iterate and add complexity.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks I will close this question then. I was just trying to ask someone if such a component is already out there. I have no problem writing it but would save me a lot of time if it is already out there. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the state of the list see it's expanded or not.

Something like this should help.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const myList = ({ list }) => {
  const MAX_COUNT = 5;
  const [isExpended, setIsExpended] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (list.length <= MAX_COUNT) {
      setIsExpended(true);
    }
  }, [list]);
  const expend = () => {
    setIsExpended(true);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {list.map((item, i) =>
          (isExpended === false && i < MAX_COUNT) || isExpended === true
            ? item.text
            : null
        )}
      </div>
      {isExpended === false ? (
        <button onClick={expend}>+ {list.length - MAX_COUNT} others</button>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default myList;
```

If you want to stick with 2 rows on any conditions there will be 2 approach to set the dynamic `MAX_COUNT`:

1: if you have a constant value for box-sizing and fonts and etc:
You can compute outerWidth of each elements (with box-sizing and elements length) and set a real `MAX_COUNT` based on that.

2: if you have responsive design:
you can render component with initial `MAX_COUNT` but hide contents with `visibility: hidden` and then computing outerWidth of each elements would be more realistic and much more easier.
in this scenario you have to fix the container height to prevent it from extending too much, just set a constant height to it, also you can change it after you get a real `MAX_COUNT`. now you can show contents with no worries.

Comment: I cannot set 5 as my `MAX_COUNT`. I can only show names in two rows initially. Let us consider a scenario in which the name is very long and I may be only able to fit 2 data entries in the two rows. In some cases, it may be able to fit 5 of them. The number of rows should be the constant not a `MAX_COUNT`

Comment: @sagar.a in this case you have to measure the sum of outerwidth of each shown items ( maybe first 10 of it would be enough) and adjust `MAX_COUNT`

Comment: @esfahani so i would need to compute the widths without rendering it to the DOM. If i add it to the dom and compute, i would need to rerender the page. If i precalculate it i would need to consider padding, font size etc. Use font size and text length for computation, i am really not sure about the approach.

Comment: @sagar.a yes it only works if you have a constant value for padding and font size and ...

Comment: But the work i am doing is for a responsive design and i think the font size are different

Comment: Maybe i need to write different implementations for mobile and web

Comment: @sagar.a also you can render component with initial `MAX_COUNT` but hide it with (visibility: hidden)   in this case you can  compute the widths and get the real `MAX_COUNT`. and after that you can show component content. this approach make a small blink for the first time but you can fake it with loading spinners or something

Comment: I dont think it will work. The container height may change. When i have visibility set to hidden then the elements will extend the container right? And after the computation the height may shrink. I think the previous approach will be better

Comment: @sagar.a aow no, you can fixed the container height and prevent it to extend too much, just set a constant height to it, also you can change it after you get a real `MAX_COUNT` , this would the easiest approach for a responsive design matter i think.

Comment: Yeah looks like these is the only way have got now. Thanks for the help. I will accept this if you mention the discussion in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201777/discussion-between-alireza-esfahani-and-sagar-a).